# Ubuntu 18.04 not detecting any wifi network but detects mobile hotspot

Tags: wireless

Complete Linux beginner here.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday, dual booting with Windows 8.1.

When trying to connect to a WiFi network, it doesn't detect any of the networks (not mine or my neighbors'). I tried creating a hotspot from my Android phone and to my surprise, it detected it immediately.

I searched around on the internet and tried restarting the network manager service, changing the channel on my router, and some other things, but nothing worked.

When I boot into Windows, my wifi along with all the other networks is detected and connects with no problem.

Edit: Here's the output of running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

> captaindroid@Akash-PC:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
>   08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
>       Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:804c]
>       Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
>       Kernel modules: rtl8723be
>   09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   TL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added the output of the command you suggested. Please have a look.

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried the suggested solution and changed the antenna both to 1 & 2, but it didn't work. I took my laptop and moved closer to the router and it detected the network. Any permanent solution?

Comment: Did you reboot after you entered the command?

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`.

Comment: @Pilot6 It turned out that the wifi driver suggested in that post did not install properly as there was some package called `libelf-dev` missing. I installed it and did the process again and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found this from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/88#issuecomment-174793423)

Doing this solved the poblem in my ubuntu 18.04

```
git clone https://github.com/rtlwifi-linux/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

and reboot.